# PHP Delete rows from MySQL where two tables don't match

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables:

```
tickets
tickets_updates
```

I think there are a few extra rows in `tickets_updates` where a record doesn't exist in the `tickets` table

What is the best way to run SQL Code to say:

Delete all from `tickets_updates` where `ticket_seq` is not in `tickets` (sequence)

sequence in the tickets table matches ticket_seq in the tickets_updates table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```sql
DELETE FROM tickets_updates
WHERE  ticket_seq NOT IN (SELECT sequence
                           FROM   tickets)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
DELETE FROM tickets_updates tu
LEFT JOIN tickets t ON tu.ticket_seq = t.sequence
WHERE t.sequence IS NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM ticket_updates
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 'x' from tickets
    WHERE tickets.sequence = ticket_updates.ticket_seq)
```

Comment: not exist is expensive in mysql. A query that cheap in writing could be expensive with execution.

Comment: Yes but NOT IN you must pay attention if set is null and another issue is about long elements list. And using on LEFT JOIN is not SQL Standard

Comment: To be fair, it's not *that* expensive.

Comment: @Strawberry. I think too that

Comment: Hm, I'm also pretty sure that LEFT [OUTER] JOIN *is* standard - and it is the method I'd adopt

Comment: @Strawberry: Hi, if you execute a DELETE statement with JOIN (LEFT or INNER is the same) on Sql Server this goes in error. More, alias on delete table in Sql Server goes in error too.

Comment: Well, I have to admit I know next to nothing about SQL server, but this fiddle (which purports to employ that engine) appears to contradict your assertion... http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1f7ae/1

Comment: @Strawberry: My dear, I've launched the query on server of Sql Server R2 2008. I don't know SQLFiddle how processes query.